# c++  printf question: How can I safely pass a char* to printf?

Tags: c++, pointers, printf

```
const char* abc = "foo";
printf(abc);
```

Is this safe or proper? I saw some legacy code including this. 
Thanks!

Very very sorry..I made a mistake, i changed it back....

Comment: FYI, formatting your code would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming there is supposed to be semicolons after those lines?

Comment: Some semicolons in the right places would help too.

Comment: I don't think this question now asks the same question that the answers answered before it was changed. In short, the answer to "Is this safe?" went from **No** to **Yes**.

Comment: sorry to everyone. My head stupid before..I changed it back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this isn't safe. Assuming `abc` points to a valid string (which it currently doesn't), this kind of pattern can be susceptible to a format-string vulnerability. Refer to [Format string attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack)

edit: I see that you fixed the code in your question. It used to pass `abc` as the first argument to `printf`, which is really, really bad. Now that you made the first argument `"%s"`, it's much better. Those two are not similar and have a huge difference in security, so look for this pattern in your legacy code.

Comment: He fixed the code, but I think that your answer is still relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming your `abc` points to an actual string rather than nothing.  Cleaning up your example code would be helpful.

I've done this in the past to write out a static string and never encountered a problem.  In retrospect, I've been lucky.  To be correct, it should probably look like:

```
const char* abc = "foo";
printf("%s", abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell from the limited code fragment in your questions

but, depends.... printf will print it as a format string.....so as long as it doesn't use any format string special characters it will be ok...

Answer (score 0):

For

```
const char* abc = "foo";
printf(abc);
```

I can't see any reason why introduce a variable abc, because 2 lines are so close.

If the abc not a const string pointer, then this is very dangerous.
Because the printf relies on argument list, which is not type safe itself, it is very easily to cause a crash or similar.